# Soomla GooglePlayIabService

Tags: android, plugins, soomla

Hi I have used the older version of soomla plugin in my android app and it was working fine, but when i try to integrate into the latest version(core version : 1.0, StoreVersion : 1.7.3) available this error pops up.

> SOOMLA GooglePlayIabService

(launchPurchaseFlow) Error purchasing item calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

> SOOMLA SoomlaStore

ERROR : SoomlaStore failure(launchPurchaseFlow) Error purchasing item Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. is this really what you want?

When i created an empty project and tried the plugin i could make the purchase successfully. Same is not happening for the project i want it to work with. Also using Facebook unity plugin. Unity version is 4.5.3.

11-24 16:38:39.497: E/SOOMLA GooglePlayIabService(12139): (launchPurchaseFlow) Error purchasing item Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
11-24 16:38:39.497: E/SOOMLA SoomlaStore(12139): ERROR: SoomlaStore failure: (launchPurchaseFlow) Error purchasing item Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

> AndroidManifest file is below.

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" android:minSdkVersion="9" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:name="com.soomla.SoomlaApp">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="behind" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.soomla.store.billing.google.GooglePlayIabService$IabActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="billing.service" android:value="google.GooglePlayIabService" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.TeenPatti.RoyalIndianPoker.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 1499084616994189" />
  </application>
</manifest>][1]
```

Here is the screenshot for the logcat error

Comment: You should really ask your SOOMLA questions on http://answers.soom.la

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be an issue with AndroidStoreGooglePlay.jar. Changing it to the latest commit fixed the issue for me [latest commit](https://github.com/soomla/unity3d-store/commit/0eb37504734a94f7904f958c68d0932e8747c11d). Hope it might help others too.